# Strange and dummy issue with UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiview

I'm developing an iOS app and I could have such a mess.
After changing some parameters in Xcode, like "clears graphic context", now all my views are like that when another view overlays them:

[image: all]

This happens with keyboard, all UIViews, TWTweetComposeViewController and any other object which overlays the view.

What could it be?

Answer (score 1):

This is from Apple docs

> When set to YES, the drawing buffer is automatically cleared to
>   transparent black before the drawRect: method is called. This behavior
>   ensures that there are no visual artifacts left over when the view’s
>   contents are redrawn. If the view’s opaque property is also set to
>   YES, the backgroundColor property of the view must not be nil or
>   drawing errors may occur. The default value of this property is YES.
>
> If you set the value of this property to NO, you are responsible for
>   ensuring the contents of the view are drawn properly in your drawRect:
>   method. If your drawing code is already heavily optimized, setting
>   this property is NO can improve performance, especially during
>   scrolling when only a portion of the view might need to be redrawn.

I think you should call self.view. clearsContextBeforeDrawing = YES from your viewDidLoad method. You can also check it off/on from Interface builder (screenshot below)

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work. I setted in my viewDidLoad `self.view.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = NO;`

but nothing changed

Comment: even so `self.view.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = YES ` doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem changing the framework to manage my view controllers.

The issue was due to [ECSlidingViewController](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController): after delete it and replace it with [ViewDeck](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck), all works like a charm and the application is significantly more fluid.